# Rails Tutorial case sensitive not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, case-sensitive

I am following Rails tutorial and after signing up for my site, I am trying to sign in.  I recently noticed in my app that if I capitalize my email address, I get the invalid username/password message.  I tested the regex on Rubular and it works with capitalization so that can't be it.

Maybe this deals with sessions?

```
 email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[csupomona\d\-.]+[edu]+\z/i

     validates :email, :presence   => true,
                        :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

Here's the code for sessions/create

```
def create
      user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing to do with validation.
It is to do with

1. How email addresses are stored in the database (assumedly some upper case, some lower case)
2. How the `User.authenticate` works (I assume it does a User.find_by_email)

Looking at the question, I've never actually had this be a problem.

But to solve it there are a couple of ways to go about this.

1. Store all emails lowercase, and make `User.authenticate` do the same
2. Ensure that `User.authenticate` is case insensitive.

But I've got a feeling that `User.authenticate` is coming from `Devise` or something similar. So 1. may be the best solution

```
class User

  # all email writes get lowercased
  def email=(value)
    self[:email] = value && value.downcase
  end

end

user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email].try(:downcase), ...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail explanation! I tried method #2 and it worked.  I learned a lot from this, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're a little confused about what that regex is for. Let us have a look at this:

```
validates :email, :presence   => true,
                  :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

Where is the regex being used? It is being used for the `:format` so the regex is only used to see if an incoming email address looks like a valid email address and that has nothing to do with uniqueness. The `:uniqueness` parameter to `validates` specifies that case shouldn't be considered when ensuring that email addresses are unique. So you can't have two users whose email addresses differ only by case.

Nothing in the code you've shown talks about how email addresses are compared when you're trying to sign someone in and that's where you're have trouble. You'll have to update your `User.authenticate` class method to do a case insensitive search for the email address.

Comment: Extremely helpful information. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.  I got more out of it than expected!